# Getting context inside onRequest function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am learning cloud functions.
I have this function:

```
exports.sendFCM = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
const data = request.body.data;
...
});
```

I need iside this function get the user UID:
const uid = context.auth.uid;
But I do not have context there.

I can get UID like this:

```
exports.getUid = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
const uid = context.auth.uid;
return `response: ${uid}`;
});
```

Basicallty, how I call getUid inside sendFCM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no context in HTTP functions at all like there is in background functions, so what you're trying to do isn't possible as you're asking.  There is only the input to the function in the Request object and the response you generate in the Response object.

If you want to know who is making the request, you need to code your app to pass along the authenticated user token in the request and validate it using the Firebase Admin SDK.  You can read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) about that.  Note that callable type functions do all this for you behind the scenes.